# Кто нибудь встречался с проблемой, когда запускаешь код, то открывается черное окно, а позже выдаёт ошибку, что Python не отвечает.Может есть ошибки?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, pygame

```
import pygame

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

pygame.init()


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption("TheCalm Adventure")
icon=pygame.image.load("images/maxresdefault.jpg") 
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

bg = pygame.image.load("images/Фон.jpg")

walk_right = [
    pygame.image.load("images/moving/22.png"), 
    pygame.image.load("images/moving/33.png"),
    pygame.image.load("images/moving/44.png"),
]
player_anim_count = 0

#player= pygame.image.load ("images/moving/22.png")

running = True
while running:
    screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))

    screen.blit(walk_right[player_anim_count], (300, 430))

    if player_anim_count == 2:
        player_anim_count = 0
    else:
        player_anim_count += 1

    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.QUIT()


    clock.tick(20)
```

(до того, как я не внес анимацию "вправо" , все работало)

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: проблема в строчке  `pygame.QUIT()` - она "выключает"  `pygame`, но не закрывает окно, которое после этого никак не реагирует на действия пользователя, поэтому и вылезает сообщение, что `Python` не отвечает :)

Comment: Я закомментировал строчку, но ничего :/

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаю о какой анимации "вправо" вы пишите.

Если ваш код нормально отформатировать, то все работает как написано.

Я добавил одну строку, чтобы было понятнее что у вас происходит.

```
import sys
import pygame

pygame.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption("TheCalm Adventure")

icon = pygame.image.load("lena.jpg")                            # 
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

bg = pygame.image.load("im.png")                                #

walk_right = [
    pygame.image.load("Ok.png"),                                #
    pygame.image.load("fg.png"),                                #
    pygame.image.load("lena2.png"),                             #
]
player_anim_count = 0

running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(60)
    screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))

    screen.blit(walk_right[player_anim_count], (100, 100))

    if player_anim_count == 2:
        player_anim_count = 0
    else:
        player_anim_count += 1

    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.wait(700)                                            # !!! +++

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            #pygame.QUIT()
            sys.exit()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**im.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Ok.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**fg.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**lena2.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я говорю о функции walk_right, без этой анимации все  спокойно работает, я еще добавил передвижение влево и вправо (без анимаций, а просто одной картинкой), но выглядит не очень...

Comment: @user560462 `walk_right` это не функция, а список. Я не вижу в вашем коде анимации.

Comment: В любом случае, не понимаю, что с этим списком не так :(